# Error : Hbase Host is in invalid State while using Hdinsight

Tags: azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight, ambari, apache-zookeeper

I am using Azure Hdinsight. When I do restart It gives following error

**"On host abc.internal.cloudapp.net role HBASE_CLIENT in invalid state.
Invalid transition. Invalid event: HOST_SVCCOMP_OP_IN_PROGRESS at INSTALL_FAILED"**

I am not able to start HMaster.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove and install again,see here [same kind question](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/28543/how-to-fix-kerberos-client-in-invalid-state-invali.html)

Remove:

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -X DELETE "http://<AMBARI-SERVER>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<cluster-name>/hosts/<host-name>/host_components/HBASE_CLIENT"
```

Install:
    Open Host UI ->  Add -> HBASE_CLIENT